# How to selected an specific Cell From the selected row of a datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to selecte the value of the first cell of the selected row in a datagrid in wpf but I have tried all selected methods that the intellicense showup but none of then worked for me I know this might be a silly question but I have no other way to answered it

[this is the image of my datagrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLaCZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

SelectedItem is an object that you need to cast to the right type, then you'll be able to access the Id property.

Here's a sample code :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<SomeObject> list = new List<SomeObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new SomeObject
            {
                Id = $"{i}{i}",
                Nombre = $"Nombre {i}"
            });
        }

        DataContext = list;
    }

    private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is DataGrid)
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
            SomeObject selectedObject = dataGrid.SelectedItem as SomeObject;
            if (selectedObject != null)
            {
                string selectedId = selectedObject.Id;
            }
        }
    }
}

internal class SomeObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Mr Leblanc I have applied the code to my class and it works perfect now thank you verify much for your help.